# UWP XAML GridView to Fill Vertical space

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a page with 2 columns
Each column has controls contained in stackpanels
The stackpanel is contained in a boarder.

border
stackpanel
.....
gridview
/stackpanel
/boarder

I want the boarder to fill the vertical height without setting the minheight to a pixel value.

Meaning I do not want the boarder to grow and shrink with the gridview, it should stay the same size, filling the colunm and respecting its margins.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="RightColumn"
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Margin="10,20,20,20">

    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Tags" />

    <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource DGreen}"
        MinHeight="500"
            BorderThickness="2" 
            Padding="10">
        <StackPanel >

            <TextBox Width="120"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                KeyDown="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddNewTag}"
                PlaceholderText="Add New Tag"
                Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.NewTagToAdd, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Text="Add Tags from this list" />

            <GridView Margin="0,10,0,0" MaxHeight="416" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SD.TagsAvailableForSelecting}"
                SelectionChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddTagToSelectedTags, Mode=OneWay}">

                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="dat:TagDTO">
                        <Border Width="90" Background="{StaticResource DGreen}">
                            <TextBlock Margin="3"
                                Foreground="{StaticResource ContrastColorBrush}"
                                Text="{x:Bind TagName}" />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>

            </GridView>

        </StackPanel>

    </Border>

</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your First `StackPanel` to `Grid`. so that It can fill the complete available space. `TextBox` will go to first Row which is set as `Auto` and Second `Border` should go to Second Row which is set as `*`.

Below is a mockup from your example.

```
<Grid x:Name="RightColumn"
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Margin="10,20,20,20">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Tags" Grid.Row="0" />

    <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource DGreen}" Grid.Row="1"
            MinHeight="500" BorderThickness="2" Padding="10">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Width="120"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                KeyDown="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddNewTag}"
                PlaceholderText="Add New Tag"
                Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.NewTagToAdd, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Text="Add Tags from this list" />
            <GridView Margin="0,10,0,0" MaxHeight="416" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SD.TagsAvailableForSelecting}"
                SelectionChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddTagToSelectedTags, Mode=OneWay}">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="dat:TagDTO">
                        <Border Width="90" Background="{StaticResource DGreen}">
                            <TextBlock Margin="3"
                                Foreground="{StaticResource ContrastColorBrush}"
                                Text="{x:Bind TagName}" />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes, now I remember, grids cells are filled.  Thanks you very much AVK Naidu.

Comment: Lets try that again. 
Yes, now I remember, grid cells are filled. Thank you very much AVK Naidu.